# Google visualization line chart Y axis border line missing

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have use google chart API first time I have create the graph with some dynamic values but one thing i have not got in my Graph is vertical border line of graph.
can any buddy suggest me what i have missed.

here is my graph screen shot : https://screenshots.firefox.com/rNOR4ePUhrhxWVxS/localhost

Comment: Will you please share a sample of the data and the options used to draw the chart?

Comment: Sounds like you have no 0 domain value.  You can force the hAxis to include 0 if you add this option:  hAxis: { viewWindow: { min: 0 }}

Comment: Thanks friends for reply, I have resolved this issue by adding hAxis min bound value as 0.